# calculating mean for part of the data in R

Tags: r

I have sort the data. I need to calculate the mean for the lowest 20% of the sample data. How do i write the command in R?

```
x<- matrix (1:10, ncol = 2)

      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10
```

i have tried the following:-

```
 es<- mean(head(x, .2 * nrow(x)))
```

but the answer is wrong. it gives me average for (1+6)/2. I want it to find the mean for the lowest 2 data in each column. It should give me answer ;

```
[,1] [,2]
 1.5  6.5
```

Thanks

Comment: 30% of what? The rows? 30% of 10 rows?

Comment: meaning that i want to find the mean only for the first 30% of the data. (2+4+6)/3 = 4 @rawr

Comment: `mean(head(data, .3 * nrow(data)))` you said bottom but you meant the 30% lowest values? not the last 30% rows?

Comment: yes. 30% of the lowest value in the data. @rawr

Comment: what if i have 2 columns? for example i have 

x<- matrix (1:10, ncol = 2)

i tried to use mean(head(x, .2 * nrow(x))), but it gives me wrong answer. 

it should be (1+2)/5 for the first column and (6+7)/2 for the second column.

@rawr

Comment: `apply(x, 2, function(x) mean(head(x, 2)))` for the first two elements of each column

Comment: that's great! tqqqqqqq @rawr

Comment: and last question, what if i want it to calculate the mean for different elements in each column? for example, first it calculates the mean for the first 20% elements in the data, then it calculates the mean for 30% elements in the data and so on. Where should i specify it? First it should give 1.5 and 6.5 answer. then it gives 2 and 7 @rawr

Comment: something like `lapply(2:5, function(ii) apply(x, 2, function(x) mean(head(x, ii))))` however this method becomes a pain if you want to skip the first few. `head` and `tail` are just (kinda hacky) quick ways to subset data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> apply(x, 2, function(z) mean(z[order(z)][1:2]) )
[1] 1.5 6.5
```

Look at `?apply` for row-wise or column-wise operations on matrices or all-numeric or all-character subsets of dataframes.

This is actually the lowest 40% of values, since 2/5 = 0.4. If you wanted this to be "sensitive" to varying lengths (and still asking for 40% rather than 20%) you would do something like:

```
> apply(x, 2, function(z) mean(z[order(z)][1:(length(z)*.4)]) )
[1] 1.5 6.5
```